# How to check if a glob has an expansion?

Tags: bash, shell-script, wildcards

Is there a good clean conventional way to do this?

For example, if there are any ".gz" files in a certain directory, I want to unzip them.  But if there aren't, I don't want to see any error.

If I use `gzip -d /mydir/*.gz`, I get the error:

```
gzip: /mydir/*.gz: No such file or directory
```

If I first `shopt -s nullglob` and then `gzip -d /mydir/*.gz`, I get the following:

```
gzip: compressed data not read from a terminal. Use -f to force decompression.
For help, type: gzip -h
```

I have one method I know will work, which I'm posting as an answer.  I'm wondering if there's a better/cleaner way.

POSIX compatibility is a bonus, but not required.

Comment: for bash this answer is very good using `compgen` command:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937407/test-whether-a-glob-has-any-matches-in-bash

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### With `bash`:

```
shopt -s nullglob
files=(/mydir/*.gz)
((${#files[@]} == 0)) || gzip -d -- "${files[@]}"
```

### With `zsh`:

```
files=(/mydir/*.gz(N))
(($#files == 0)) || gzip -d -- $files
```

Note that in `zsh`, without `(N)`, like in pre-Bourne shells, csh or tcsh, if the glob doesn't match, the command is not run, you'd only do the above to avoid the resulting error message (of *no match found* as opposed to `gzip` failing on the expanded glob in the case of `bash` or other Bourne-like shells). You can achieve the same result with `bash` with `shopt -s failglob`.

In `zsh`, a failing glob is a fatal error that causes the shell process where it's expanded (when not interactive) to exit. You can prevent your script from exiting in that case either by using a subshell or using `zsh` error catching mechanism (`{ try-block; } always { error-catching; }`), (or by setting the `nonomatch` (to work like `sh`), `nullglob` or `noglob` option of course, though I wouldn't recommend that):

```
$ zsh -c 'echo zz*; echo not output'
zsh:1: no matches found: zz*
$ zsh -c '(echo zz*); echo output'
zsh:1: no matches found: zz*
output
$ zsh -c '{echo zz*;} always {TRY_BLOCK_ERROR=0;}; echo output'
zsh:1: no matches found: zz*
output
$ zsh -o nonomatch -c 'echo zz*; echo output'
zz*
output
```

Note that if the glob is passed to an external command, it's only the process that was forked to execute the command that exits:

```
$ zsh -c '/bin/echo zz*; echo still output and the previous command exited with $?'
zsh:1: no matches found: zz*
still output and the previous command exited with 1
```

### With ksh93

`ksh93` eventually added a mechanism similar to `zsh`'s `(N)` glob qualifier to avoid having to set a `nullglob` option globally:

```
files=(~(N)/mydir/*.gz)
((${#files[@]} == 0)) || gzip -d -- "${files[@]}"
```

### POSIXly

Portably in POSIX `sh`, where non-matching globs are passed unexpanded with no way to disable that behaviour (the only POSIX glob related option is `noglob` to disable globbing altogether), the trick is to do something like:

```
set -- /mydir/[*].gz /mydir/*.gz
case $#$1$2 in
   '2/mydir/[*].gz/mydir/*.gz') : no match;;
   *) shift; gzip -d -- "$@"
esac
```

The idea being that if `/mydir/*.gz` doesn't match, then it will expand to itself (`/mydir/*.gz`). However, it could also expand to that if there was one file actually called `/mydir/*.gz`, so to differentiate between the cases, we also use the `/mydir/[*].gz` glob that would also expand to `/mydir/*.gz` if there was a file called like that.

As that's pretty awkward, you may prefer using `find` in those cases:

```
find /mydir/. ! -name . -prune ! -name '.*' \
   -name '*.gz' -type f -exec gzip -d {} +
```

The `! -name . -prune` is to not look into subdirectories (some `find` implementations have `-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1` as an equivalent). `! -name '.*'` is to exclude hidden files like globs do.

Another benefit is that it still works if the list of files is too big to fit in the limit of the size of arguments to an executed command (`find` will run several `gzip` commands if need to avoid that, `ksh93` (with `command -x`) and `zsh` (with `zargs`) also have mechanisms to work around that).

Another benefit is that you will get error messages if `find` cannot read the content of `/mydir` or can't determine the type of the files (globs would just silently ignore the problem and act as if the corresponding files don't exist).

A small down side is that you lose the exact value of `gzip`'s exit status (if any one `gzip` invocation fails with a non-zero exit status, `find` will still exit with a non-zero exit status (though not necessarily the same) though, so that's good enough for most use cases).

Another benefit is that you can add the `-type f` to avoid trying to uncompress directories or fifos/devices/sockets... whose name ends in `.gz`. Except in `zsh` (`*.gz(.)` for regular files only), globs cannot filter by file types, you'd need to do things like:

```
set --
for f in /mydir/*.gz
  [ -f "$f" ] && [ ! -L "$f" ] && set -- "$@" "$f"
done
[ "$#" -eq 0 ] || gzip -d -- "$@"
```

Comment: Thanks!  I guess there is no super-easy way in `bash`; mine seems okay too.  And I guess there's no `nullglob` in POSIX, right?

Comment: `find` is pure POSIX and fairly easy to understand, so this should be the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is:

```sh
shopt -s nullglob
for f in /mydir/*.gz; do
  gzip -d /mydir/*.gz
  break
done
```

The `for` loop with nullglob set on will only execute the loop at all if the glob has an expansion, and the unconditional `break` statement ensures that the `gzip` command will only be executed once.

It's a bit funny because it uses a `for` loop as an `if`, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be

```
for f in *.gz; do
  test -f "$f" && gzip -d -- "$f"
done
```

or

```
for f in *.gz; do
  [ -f "$f" ] && gzip -d -- "$f"
done
```

or even

```
for f in *.gz; do
  if [ -f "$f" ]; then
    gzip -d -- "$f"
  fi
done
```

I'm all for verbosity if it help explain what the code does.  The various shells have compact syntax for doing all sorts of things, but it doesn't beat the above when it comes to documenting what you're doing (and portability).  I'm thinking primarily about shell scripting here, and situations in which your scripts may be used and modified by others.

**EDIT:**

If you just want to see if the glob has an expansion:

```
if [ "$(printf '%s' *.gz)" = "*.gz" ] && [ ! -f "*.gz" ]; then
    # From Stéphane Chazelas: "There are no gzipped files that I
    # can tell, or if there's one, it's called *.gz and it is not a
    # regular file (after symlink resolution) or at least I can't tell
    # if it's a regular file or not."

    echo "There are no gzipped files"
else
    echo "There are gzipped files"
fi
```

See also Stéphane's further comments below regarding exotic file names.

Comment: For `gunzip` this may work, but for some commands, e.g. `tar`, it's necessary to run the command itself on the entire list of files at once rather than one by one.  Although you could use `for f in *.gz; do [ -e "$f" ] && gzip -d *.gz; break; done`, I suppose.  That obviates any need for "nullglob."

Comment: @Wildcard The most _common_ use case for creating a `tar` archive is to archive a directory rather than individual files.

Comment: Note that `[ -f "$file" ]` tests whether `$file` is accessible (as in one can do a `stat()` on it) and is of type _regular_ after symlink resolution, so it will give true for symlinks to regular files, and false for symlinks to inaccessible files or in the case of `/mydir/*.gz` if you don't have _search_ permission to `/mydir`

Comment: Stricktly speaking, the _"There are no gzipped files"_ should be _"There are no gzipped files that I can tell, or if there's one, it's called *.gz and it is not a regular file (after symlink resolution) or at least I can't tell if it's a regular file or not"_. See the `*.gz`, `[*].gz` trick to avoid having to rely on `stat()`.

Comment: A downside is that it runs one `gzip` command per file. That also means that if gunzip fails for one file (except the last one), that won't be reflected in the exit status (though in most cases, you'll still get an error message). (a problem that affects find approaches as well)

Comment: Note that with Unix compliant echos, `"$(echo *.gz)"` would expand to `*.gz` if there was a file called `*.gz\canything.gz` in the current directory (and possibly others provided they sort after that one). See also `\052.gz`, `*\056gz` and so on. More generally, you can't use `echo` for arbitrary data.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I hadn't noticed tho OB marker on `-a` and `-o`, thanks! As for your last comment, I need to stop somewhere. I'll leave a note in the answer instead.

Comment: @Kusalananda, or you could follow the POSIX recommendation of using printf instead of echo for arbitrary data. IMO, it's better to encourage best practice.